# Sentinel KQL Query not projecting columns from leftouter join

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I have a KQL query which works in Defender and returns all the data I need, however when I run it in Log Analytics in Sentinel, the IdentityInfo columns referenced by the leftouter join are not returned.  I need this data to create custom emails from a Logic App

The KQL query is below.  I need to return the GivenName, Surname and AccountUpn columns from IdentityInfo

```
 DeviceFileEvents
| where (tolower(FileName) endswith ".msi" or tolower(FileName) endswith ".exe")
| where SHA1 != ""
| where 
    // Edge
    InitiatingProcessFolderPath endswith @"windows\system32\browser_broker.exe" 
    // Internet Explorer x64
    or InitiatingProcessFolderPath endswith @"program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
    // Internet Explorer x32
    or InitiatingProcessFolderPath endswith @"program files (x86)\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
    // Chrome
    or (InitiatingProcessFileName =~ "chrome.exe")
    // Firefox
    or (InitiatingProcessFileName =~ "firefox.exe" and (FileName !endswith ".js" or FolderPath !has "profile"))
| join kind=leftouter (IdentityInfo) on $left.RequestAccountName == $right.AccountName
| join kind=innerunique(DeviceProcessEvents  
    | where SHA1 != ""
    | where FileName contains ".exe" 
    | where (ProcessCommandLine contains ".exe") 
    )
    on $left.FileName == $right.FileName and $left.DeviceId == $right.DeviceId
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `IdentityInfo` table is existed in your Sentinel workspace. Make sure that the `IdentityInfo` database has been ingested into your workspace. Verify it using the below query:

```bash
Identiyinfo
| take 10
```

If there are no logs existed regarding the above table, it doesn't retrieve any output as shown.

[image]

If still the issue persists, try using [`union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuremonitor) operator to combine the Device file events & identity info instead of `join` operator as shown.

```bash
union DeviceFileEvents, IdentityInfo
....your query here
```